# How to block free shipping method in frontend only in magento

Tags: magento

I am in a tensed situation. I am behind this for more than 1 day. Is there anyway to block showing free shipping method in checkout page, but showing it on admin panel page.

**For eg: i purchased a product paying shipping charges for shipping method. But it is not delivered , In that case, through admin Panel, admin may able to reorder the same quote, free of cost and shipping charges, so free shipping method should show in admin panel. But When I enable that, this is shown on frontend also, so how can I block free shipping in frontend(customer checkout), but keeping it enable in admin panel.**

I am sorry for poor English. I think, the example that i provided you make the question clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific or give a code example?
I'm not good with php and this free shipping is something very unlogical for me to let customer choose by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is , just edit the shipping methods template and make a if condition by shipping method code or extend the shipping method and set the isActive method to distinct front and backend

Comment: Thanks, Anton; Please will you provide me path from where I can find shipping methods template.

Comment: Thanks Anton, After a long search I find to block free shipping in Front end only.                                                               In **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php**, in **collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)** method i provided the store id of admin page for display and by that i have blocked frontend shipping.

Comment: in the same method implement public isActive(

Comment: Interestingly this onle seems to work when an order has a value greater than 1 dollar. When we enter an internal order for 0 (free) the free shipping option is not shown

Comment: Somehow it still isnt working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941784/magento-how-do-i-manual-order-backend-free-shipping-actually-pickup