# magento How do I? manual order (backend) free shipping, actually pickup

Tags: magento

magento How do I? manual order (backend) free shipping, actually pickup

Hi we want to be able to enter order in the adminhtml backend (we enter for customer).

Our problems are

1) the customer pays us cash. How do we enable this only for the backend (now we have to select credit card,- the option availbale on checkout)

2) The customer wants to pickup. But we dont want to offer this option to all customers via checkout. So this option is only available for us in the backend

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow cash payment in the Model:

```
public function  isAvailable($quote = null)
{
    return (parent::isAvailable($quote) && Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin());
}
```

This will enable you payment method only in Admin.

Comment: Will try this, thanks. Would this also be an option for free shipping to be shown in backend only? (same principle) + in what file do put this code?

Comment: Is the same way, you only have to do it in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping::isActive

Comment: Hi Rapheal. Didnt get it to work. I dont see a isActive. We tried to change this code in core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {

  // Changed to allow free shipping in backend SEAN MAY2012
  // if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
  // return false;
  // }

  if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
   return false;
  }

Comment: isActive is a superclass method (from Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract), you can override it in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping

Comment: Hi Rafael, suppose I would want to extend/override via extension?

Comment: There are thousands of files with the word Model in the title. As snh_nl asked, to which specific file should enter your isAvailable function?

Answer (score 1):

For free shipping at backend, I suggest trying this free module. It gives you a option of adding a custom shipping rate while creating order at the backend, that you can always set to zero according to your needs.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-custom-shipping-rate.html

As far as pay by cash is concerned, you can use the check/moneyorder payment method, and just hide the phtml code for this method on the frontend.

Comment: Must update: this code breaks the whole order emailing function. There is a loop in the Order.Php that runs out of index because it starts looking for an unkown sending method.

It looks like this works, but in the end the whole email functionality doesnt work anymore

Comment: my email works with this module. Would you please elaborate ?

Comment: I add a product manually via the backend (as admin). Create customer, create order. Then use the above Extension. Set shipping to Manual as text and value to 0,0 euro. Then go back and invoice + ship. The email is not being sent + my logs show "index out of bounds error" around line 1218 in Order.php